# What is .lib file contain while generating DLL

Tags: c++, dll

I am generating .dll in visual studio 2010. .lib, .dll, .pdb files are getting generated in output folder.

1. why .lib (is it static lib?) is genarating along with dll, what is the use of it and 
   what it contains actually ?
   (In linux along with .so it can not have any other files, but why in Windows).
2. what is this .pdb files, what it contains and how will it be usefull ?

Thanaks in advance :)

Comment: `.lib` contains stub functions, that will get the functions from the DLL at runtime, `.pdb` files contains the dbugger symbol tables.

Comment: [Google: "why does windows generate lib for dll", first hit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Have you done any research yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.lib` alongwith `.dll` is not static library. It tells the linker that the functions present in `lib` are to be loaded from the `dll`. By this, it creates dependency on the dll. Failing to find the dll will cause application to quit (which is checked at the time of start).

It is used in implicit linking of dll.

PDB file is used by debugger to find symbol information.

Answer (score 3):

> Why .lib (is it static lib?) is generating along with dll, what is the use of it and what it contains actually ?

No, that .lib is a import library and it is used in implicit linking.

> What is this .pdb files, what it contains and how will it be useful ?

PDB file contains Symbol & line information and they are used by debugger to map hex/oct addresses to function names. PDB file is generated when your build your project.

without PDB your program stack trace would look like this

```
0x00002130
```

with PDB

```
0x00002130 yourprogram!function
```